# Unable to get keys from RocksDB given large database size and column families

Tags: python, python-3.x, rocksdb

I want to get all the keys from RocksDB but I get an empty list when I try to create a `list` of the iterator:

```
it = db.iterkeys()
it.seek_to_first()
```

The database contains data, I am sure of that. For the sake of providing minimal viable code, [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uK4MZJH2ZEHKfJU412jrO3ESbHc-pt2d?usp=sharing) is the database. My complete code is:

```
import rocksdb
from pprint import pprint
column_families = {}
columns = ["col9", "col8", "col7", "col6", "col5", "col4", "col3", "col2", "col1", "col11", "col0", "col10"]
for column in columns:
    column_families[bytes("{}".format(column), encoding='utf-8')] = rocksdb.ColumnFamilyOptions()


db_path = "db"
db = rocksdb.DB(db_path, rocksdb.Options(create_if_missing=False), column_families = column_families)

print("DB opened.")

it = db.iterkeys()
it.seek_to_first()

keys = list(it)
counter = 0
for key in keys:
    print(key)
    if counter == 10:
        break
    counter += 1
```

At first, I was just reading the database but got error to include column families, which resolved the "Unable to open DB" error but I am not getting an empty list of keys.

How do I get all the keys?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which column family you are going to iterating. Say, if you want to read all keys stored with column family 'col9', you can try the following:

```
col9_cf_handle = db.get_column_family(b'col9')
it = db.iterkeys(col9_cf_handle)
it.seek_to_first()
```